# How to update address of current location in textfield from Google map for android applicatioin

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am working working on creating app which get an address of current location and update them as the location changes from Google map.

It is currently working fine but it does not update. 
I am displaying the address on text view and the current location mark on Google map changes as current location changes but the address does not reflect the change.
It only show address of first location and does not update...

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks very much in advance.

Here is my codes below;

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setClickable(true);

    map.getController().setZoom(17);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address_label);

    overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(getApplicationContext(), map);
    overlay.onProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    overlay.enableMyLocation();


    overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            GeoPoint g = overlay.getMyLocation();
            map.getController().animateTo(g);
            map.getController().setCenter(g);

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale
                    .getDefault());
            boolean chk1 = isNetworkAvailable();
            if (chk1 == true) {

                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                            g.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                            g.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                    add="";
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0)
                                .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                            add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + ", ";
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ui_handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(add);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                ui_handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText("Connection not found.");

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

    map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
    map.invalidate();

}
```

Comment: You are only performing the location retrieval once - in onCreate() which is the first time your activity is created.  if you want continuous updates you need to perform it periodically (or set a listener for location change) that will update the address

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That make sense. But I have no idea how to do that...  If you don't mind would you tell me how to achieve that please. Is it just add same sort of code in onCreate() to onLocationChanged method??

Comment: >inistel I tried with writing codes in onLocationChanged method but now luck so far.. More I think about it. I am confused because the overlay(mark on map) updates its location but not the address. Since it runs thread I think the way I am doing should work but have no idea why its not.

Comment: Look at LocationListener and locationManager.requestLocationUpdates().  there you can define when to receive location changes, once you get them in onLocationChanged() retrive the address and update it in your activity

Comment: Thanks for your advice!! I got them working now. Much appreciated!!